# Teratermのデフォルトの文字コードをsjisにしたい

Tags: teraterm

また同じ質問をしてしまうかもしれませんが・・・
[前回](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/q/52235/3060)は説明が下手過ぎて、何をやりたいのか見ている人に伝わっていないと思ったので再度ご指導お願いします。

私のパソコンから外部のサーバーにつなげています。

外部のサーバーにはpostgresqlでEncodingはSQL_ASCIIです。
SQL_ASCIIなのでその中の日本語の文字コードはSJISで保存されています。

おそらく、Teratermのデフォルトの設定がUTF-8になっている為文字化けを起こしています。

毎回`set client_encoding to 'sjis'`をこちらから打ち込まないと日本語が表示されません。

これを自動的に`set client・・・`としないで、ログインして`select * from table_name;`とかしたら日本語を確認したいです。
デフォルトの設定をsjisにすればよいのかなと思っております。

Comment: 質問は後からでも [編集] できますので、元質問が解決していないのであれば[元質問](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/q/52235/3060)に対して情報を追記すべきかと思います。

Answer (score 1):

本当にtera termの設定の問題ですか？

> set client_encoding to 'sjis'

これは利用されているサーバでコマンドをたたくのですよね？サーバのログインユーザの利用しているロケールがja_JP.UTF8とかになっていませんか？そしてそのデータベースにデータを入れると秋の文字コードはなんでしたか？
つまり、サーバのロケールとpostgresが保持しているデータの文字コードにアンマッチが起きていて結果として「化ける」のでは？と考えてしまいます。もちろん、teratermも独自に端末設定として利用する文字コードを保持していますが。。。ログイン先のサーバでコマンドで治るなら、こちらの原因じゃないかと思います。
というかSQL_ASCIIだからSJISってなんでいえるのか不明です。そしてSJISはJIS90？ MS932?どれを指していますか？

Comment: > set client_encoding to 'sjis'
これはpostgresでたたくのですね。となると、意味としては「端末側の文字コードはsjisだからsjisに変換して表示してね」じゃないでしょうか。すると、本当にデータはsjisですか？
これを何とかしたいなら、
1. 端末の設定をデータに合わせる（でもSJISではなさそうじゃないですか？) 、2.postgeres側に設定を仕込むのいずれじゃないでしょうか。明示的に指定しない場合、OS側のlocaleに従うのかはpostgres次第ですね。